# Google Cloud Storage - Load Balancer - Host and path rules

Tags: load-balancing, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a website, with a *Google Cloud Load Balancer*, called `santi.com`

I have a *Google Cloud Storage Bucket* called `santi-pictures`

I have successfully setup a **Host and path rule** from this Load Balancer to this Bucket by entering this information in the Google Cloud Console.

```
+-----------+-------------+----------------+
| Hosts     | Paths       | Backends       |
+-----------+-------------+----------------+
| santi.com | /pictures/* | santi-pictures |
+-----------+-------------+----------------+
```

It works correctly when I access this url in the browser...

```
http://santi.com/pictures/me.jpg
```

... **as long as there is a picture in this location** in the bucket:

```
gs://santi-pictures/pictures/me.jpg
```

But how can I **change my load balancer configuration** so that I can instead get this following picture when I use the url mentioned above:

```
gs://santi-pictures/me.jpg
```

This is already a pictures bucket, so it doesn't make sense to me to have to put a folder called pictures in it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I tested with following host and path rules and verified with http://load-balancer-ip/file-name and was able to access the file present within the root of the bucket defined in backend configuration of the load balancer.

|        Hosts  |     Paths       | Backends    |

| WEB-SERVER-IP |  /*  | Backend-service-name |

Try copying the image within the root of the your bucket defined in backend configuration of Load balancer and add or change the "Host and path rules" to define path as "/*" (without quotes). You should be able to access the image using "gs://bucket-name/file-name" or "http://load-balancer-ip/file-name"

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I was hoping to do the same thing as @santiago-arizti, but I don't believe it's possible as of writing this. According to the [google docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/#troubleshooting):

> The Cloud Storage object to serve is determined based on your URL map and the URL that you request. If the request path maps to a backend bucket in your URL map, the Cloud Storage object is determined by appending the full request path onto the Cloud Storage bucket that the URL map specifies.
>
> For example, if you map /static/* to gs://[EXAMPLE_BUCKET], the request to https:///static/path/to/content.jpg will try to serve gs://[EXAMPLE_BUCKET]/static/path/to/content.jpg

Comment: I have gotten used to the way it works today, and now I think of it in retrospective, I think it would have caused a lot of headaches if I had mapped the urls/paths in a custom way

Answer (score 1):

Still, as of December 30th, 2019, this is not currently possible in Google Cloud CDN. It wasn't possible on AWS either, but with AWS' Lambda @ Edge offering from last year, you can rewrite URLs to your preference, as well as do any compute on the edge such as authentication or other custom workflows using Lambda functions. Even though the original poster was able to make it work without the URL rewrite, IMO it's a strong feature if you need compute at the CDN edge, actually. In fact it is one of Cloudflare CDN's big unique value proposition (called Cloudflare Workers). Google has been slow in making progress on their Cloud Function integrations with their other services, but I can imagine this integration existing on Google Cloud CDN in a couple years.